# VBA creating report in Word doc from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created a dashboard in Excel and am trying to create a button that when pressed, creates a report in Word. Currently having two issues with the code, first is formatting of the text, second is copying and pasting charts. I  was able to pull text over and format as a heading but the code I was using is now giving an error, as noted in the code below.

As for copying the chart, I get the commented error when I try to copy the chart. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct syntax as I copied it from another thread on here.

```
Sub NewReportDoc()

On Error Resume Next

Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
Set wdsel = wdApp.Selection


wdsel.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1") ' Run-time error "430"; Class does not support automation
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:="Dashboard Report "
    wdApp.Selection.InsertDateTime
    wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph


Sheets("Sheet5").CharObjects("Chart21").ChartArea.Copy ' Run-time error "9"; Subscript ran out of range
wdApp.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
Placement:=wdInLine, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False


End Sub
```

Current output is a doc with Dashboard Report 9/13/2019 at the top in normal font and nothing else

Comment: Is the missing `t` in `CharObjects` just a typo in your question?

Comment: Sound like there’s no Sheet5 or no Chart21

Comment: Step one, remove `On Error Resume Next` and forget it exists. `ActiveDocument` should be qualified with `wdApp` (that looks like a leaked implicit object - verify that you don't have lingering WINWORD.EXE ghost processes in Task Manager). As for the index out of range, it's either because `ActiveWorkbook` doesn't have any sheets named "Sheet5" (likely, given the typo that immediately follows - that would be error 438, not 9), or (assuming no typo in your actual code) there's no `Chart` named "Chart21" on this "Sheet5" worksheet.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you! That worked. Any chance you know of a way to scale the chart down in size?

Comment: `ChartObject` should have [`Width`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.width) and [`Height`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.height) read/write properties.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the help. One last question, do you know how to add a page break? I am trying to add a break between two sections of the report with 'wdApp.Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak' but the output is only the first page contents and does nothing with the rest of the content

Comment: I know how with the Excel object model, but I don't work with Word's much. It's most likely already asked and answered somewhere on this site though.

Comment: Make sure that you have word selected as a reference in the VBIDE so that you get intellisense for Word objects.  Record a macro in Word that inserts a pagebreak (or even better a section break).  Then use F1 to bring up the MS Help pages for things you don't understand.  Be aware that the macro recorder produces terrible code but is useful for researching 'How do I...'  type questions.